# How can I make the first row in excel into a drop down list to filter the column data?

Tags: excel

I have a column of data with various things. I want to turn the first row of the column into that drop down list where I can filter all of the below data. When I try data validation it doesnt filter the data when I chose from the list.

Comment: Right, because data validation affects the cell it's applied to and doesn't apply filtering to other cells. What's wrong with using a built-in filter?

Comment: Is there a built in filter to do what I am asking?

Comment: Its literally the option called filter, got it.

Comment: Since this is not a programming question, https://superuser.com/ is probably a better place to ask it btw.

Answer (score 0):

The option called filter does this automatically after you highlight the whole column.